# can't reach my site through port 80 - server is up, apache is up and fine.. any clue?

Tags: apache-2.2, hosting

Site was up fine running, I didn't do any tinkering at all and just randomly I can't seem to access port 80.

I've submitted a ticket to my host ( Rackspace ) but just wondering if anyone had a similar dilemma and if so what the cause was.

I did a dig of my domain ( there are multiple sites ) and the A record is pointing to the right IP, I don't think its a DNS issue.

```
wget sitename.com 
--2009-08-17 20:56:44-- sitename.com 
Resolving www.sitename.com... ( ip addr ) 
Connecting to www.sitename.com|(ip addr)|:80... connected. HTTP request sent, awaiting response..
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your host in a cloud or a dedicated server? can you try and reach port 80 locally from the machine itself? if you can then you will want to tell the rackers it is most likely a firewall issue.

Comment: It isn't in a cloud, its on dedicated.

Comment: What's weird is that it actually loaded at random intervals and then stopped.. and I'm testing multiple domains hosted, not just one.

Comment: Since it's not a cloud that limits the possible causes.  Either a connectivity issue between your host->rackspace, a connectivity to the datacenter at rackspace or a firewall issue at rackspace.

I'd recommend trying to hit it from an alternate location, a 3rd party website which pings the site, connects http, etc... btw not marketing a product here however I recommend checking out www.pingdom.com they have a free trial to monitor a single site.  We have used it for some of our clients.

Answer (score 1):

Have Rackspace check your firewall (assuming you are renting a dedicated one).  When we were with Rackspace and they were having all sorts of power issues our firewall lost a bunch of settings for our environment.